# What is wrong with this Binomial Tree Backwards Induction European Call Option Pricing Function?

Tags: python, numpy

The function below works perfectly and only needs one thing:
Removal of the for loop that creates the 1000 element array arr.

Can you help me get rid of that for loop?
Code is below

```
#Test with european call
import numpy as np
T = 1
N = 1000
sigma = 0.5
r = 0.02
S = 1
K = 0.7
u = np.exp(sigma*np.sqrt(T/N))
d = 1/u

arr = np.zeros(N+1)    
arr[0] = S*np.power(u,N)

coeff = np.exp(-r*(T/N))
p = (np.exp(r*(T/N))-d)/(u-d)       

for i in range(1, N+1):
    arr[i] = arr[i-1] * (d/u)     

def get_payoff(S=arr, K=K): 
    payoff = np.maximum((S - K), 0)
    return payoff

payoff = get_payoff()

def binomial_tree(payoff,S,K,T,r,sigma,N):
    for i in range(0, N):
        upper_vector = np.delete(payoff, N - i)
        lower_vector = np.delete(payoff, 0)
        payoff = coeff*(p*upper_vector + (1-p)*lower_vector)   
    return payoff[0]

print(binomial_tree(payoff,1,0.7,1,0.02,0.5,1000))
```

Comment: do you have a reference where the model is defined?

Comment: please format your code correctly, it does not run as-is

Comment: Actually, this isn't a terrible question. Not great for sure, but I don't think you deserved -6 for this. Unless of course you got them before editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am note sure if you can omit that loop in an efficient way, but when we do not use `np.delete()` but just use the indices to shrink `payoff` in every iteration I already got a big speed increase on my machine:

```py
# ...
arr = np.full(N+1, d/u)
arr[0] = S*np.power(u, N)
arr[1:] = arr[0] * np.cumprod(arr[1:])

def get_payoff(s, k):
    return np.maximum((s - k), 0)

payoff = get_payoff(arr, K)

def binomial_tree(payoff,S,K,T,r,sigma,N):
    for i in range(0, N):
        payoff = coeff*(p*payoff[:-1] + (1-p)*payoff[1:])
    return payoff[0]
```

Note that I also changed the generation of `arr` to be without a loop and changed the name of the `payload()` function so that it does not interfere with the variable name.

---

## EDIT

I asked a similar question because I thought your formula was interesting and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64309626/7570817) from Frank Yellin also applies here (so all credits to him):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom

binomial = binom(p=p, n=N)
pmf = binomial(np.arange(N+1))
res = coeff**n*np.sum(payoff * pmf)
```

In this form it is also clearer what is calculated in your loop:
the expected value of the binomial distributed random variable payoff.