# Iterative Binomial Update without Loop

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, binomial-coefficients

Can this be done without a loop?

```
import numpy as np
n = 10
x = np.random.random(n+1)
a, b = 0.45, 0.55

for i in range(n):
    x = a*x[:-1] + b*x[1:]
```

I came across this setup in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64144956/what-is-wrong-with-this-binomial-tree-backwards-induction-european-call-option-p/64298637#64298637). There it was a covered by a little obscure nomenclature. I guess it is related to [Binomial options pricing model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_options_pricing_model) but don't quite understand the topic to be honest. I just was intrigued by the formula and this iterative update / shrinking of `x` and wondered if it can be done without a loop. But I can not wrap my head around it and I am not sure if this is even possible.

What makes me think that it might work is that this vatiaton

```py
n = 10
a, b = 0.301201, 0.59692
x0 = 123
x = x0
for i in range(n):
    x = a*x + b*x
# ~42
```

is actually just `x0*(a + b)**n`

```py
print(np.allclose(x, x0*(a + b)**n))
# True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating:

```
sum( a ** (n - i) * b ** i * x[i] * choose(n, i) for 0 <= i <= n)
```

[That's meant to be pseudocode, not Python.] I'm not sure of the best way to convert that into Numpy.

`choose(n, i)` is `n!/ (i! (n-i)!)`, not the numpy choose function.

---

Using `@mathfux`'s comment, one can do

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binom

binomial = binom(p=p, n=n)
pmf = binomial(np.arange(n+1))
res = np.sum(x * pmf)
```

So

```py
res = x.copy()
for i in range(n):
    res = p*res[1:] + (p-1)*res[:-1]
```

is just the expected value of a binomial distributed random variable x.

Comment: You can check out `scipy.stats.binom`. Hope this helps to get your solution complete. But I'm not sure if a question is related with probability mass function.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It looked familiar but I couldn't put my finger on it

Comment: Thanks for the code, @scleronomic.  I didn't know about scipy.stats.  I just knew the math.